# How to distribute custom library builds with a .deb package?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, packaging

My company uses a set of internal programs that require custom builds of third-party libraries (like OpenCV).

These libraries exist in the Ubuntu repositories, but these existing packages weren't built with the options we need. As a result, we need to build them ourselves, and distribute them along with our internal programs.

I would like to distribute the whole build result (our executables, along with the custom library builds) as a `.deb` package, to make deployment and upgrade easier.

If I installed these custom builds in `/usr`, they could conflict with Ubuntu's standard packages for the same libraries. Some of them don't even put a version number in the shared object files' names.

Is it acceptable to make a `.deb` package that installs custom library builds in `/usr/local`, if it's only for internal use?

Answer (score 0):

A subdirectory under `/opt` would be a better choice.  `/usr/local` should be reserved for the machine's owner or system administrator.